# What is 'name['name'] for name in names[:-1]' in python

Tags: python

```
def namelist(names):
    if len(names) > 1:
        return '{} & {}'.format(', '.join(name['name'] for name in names[:-1]),names[-1]['name'])
    elif names:
        return names[0]['name']
    else:
        return ''
```

This is the code which joins a dictionary containing the names with correct punctuation. I need a bit of help to understand it. I can't understand what the following part means:

```
name['name'] for name in names[:-1]
```

what does `name['name']` do?

Comment: Assuming `names` is a list of dictionaries?

Comment: This code doesn't work if `names` is a dictionary, because you can't do `names[:-1]`.

Comment: @Ollie, `names` is probably a `list` of `dict`s. Not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from this example:

```
names = [{'name': 'Peter'}, {'name': 'Frank'}, {'name': 'Alice'}]
```

`names[:-1]` is a list that contains all the elements of `names` without the last one:

```
>>> names[:-1]
[{'name': 'Peter'}, {'name': 'Frank'}]
```

In your code, `name` is an element of the list `names`, which is a dictionary. `name['name']` returns the value for the key `name`.

`(name['name'] for name in names[:-1])` is a generator that yields each `name` attribute of the dictionaries called `name` of the list `names`, without the last item:

```
>>> list(name['name'] for name in names[:-1])
['Peter', 'Frank']
```

Then, `', '.join(name['name'] for name in names[:-1])` is the list of all the names without the last one, separated by commas.

```
>>> ', '.join(name['name'] for name in names[:-1])
'Peter, Frank'
```

The function `namelist` format a list of people:

```
>>> namelist(names)
'Peter, Frank & Alice'
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably helps to see an example. Imagine that `names` is this:

```
names = [
    {'age': 20, 'name': 'steve'},
    {'age': 17, 'name': 'alice'},
    {'age': 18, 'name': 'suzy'},
]
```

Then `names[:-1]` excludes the last item:

```
print(last_missing[:-1])
# prints: [{'age': 20, 'name': 'steve'}, {'age': 17, 'name': 'alice'},]
```

Then `[name['name'] for name in names[:-1]]` selects just the `'name'` entry in the dictionaries:

```
print([name['name'] for name in names[:-1]])
# prints ['steve', 'alice']
```